# Automapper vs mapping at runtime via config file and reflection

Tags: reflection, orm, mapping, linq-to-xml, automapper

I am new to this topic and I would like to know your opinion what I should do or how I can solve the following:

I am developing a C# web service client which retrieves data from a database behind the web service. The web service response holds the data in an CDATA element as an XML. The xsd schema is available. In the XML are elements that represent one dataset/row. I have to use only a few fields of one dataset. After the data retrieved I have to check some business rules/conditions and write those fields to another system. Reading some values from the other system, check some business rules and sending them back to the web service encapsulated in an appropriate XML format according to the schema.

What I have done so far. I used XSD.exe to generate c# classes according to the underlying schema. I think I have the following options to get my scenario work:

1. ORM framework:
   This should be overkill for my app. Or it is not a solution since I don´t communicate with a database directly.
2. Automapper:
   Seems to be a good solution. But I think it is not that flexibel like my 3. option (see beyond). If an error in the mapping is detected after my app was deployed, I have to rebuild the app. Another negative point would be, if the schema changes, I would have to rebuild my app again. (Or do I have always adapt my app according to the schema?)
3. Via custom mapping file and reflection:
   I am not sure if this is really realizable, but it would be the most flexible solution in my opinion. The solution would be similar to this http://www.techrepublic.com/article/applied-reflection-dynamically-accessing-properties-of-a-class-at-runtime/6099345
   If I understood this article correct, then there would be a config file that maps the type of class and its properties to destination types, for example:
   SourceClassType=ClassA, SourcePropertyName=PropA->DestinationClassType=ClassB, DestinationPropertyName=PropX.
4. Linq2Xml:
   With Linq2Xml I could extract the required data from the XML and put it in my own defined classes. But how would I put data back into the XML according to schema that the web service expects?

Is my analysis correct? Did I misunderstood something? What would you recommend? Any other options I have?

Answer (score 0):

> If an error in the mapping is detected after my app was deployed, I
>   have to rebuild the app. Another negative point would be, if the
>   schema changes, I would have to rebuild my app again. (Or do I have
>   always adapt my app according to the schema?)

There are different ways to avoid having to rebuild an app as a result of required code changes.  One way is to compile and use a component dynamically.  This can be a source code file for example.  This decision involves many factors such as how often will a change be required, who will be making the change(s), how important is performance, etc.

Another option could be to use xslt to transform the xml input into xml output, but it may depend on what the specific requirements are in your business rules.

What I would do is use xml (de)serialization and Automapper.  Deserialize the xml to an object, use automapper and your custom business logic to convert the source to the destination object, and then serialize the destination object to xml as your output.